# How can I Open and read a txt file attachment using VBA in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automate a process where I get an email with an attached file txt

I open and I check the date on the second line and saved to a folder with that date in a particular location.

With this code and a message rule in Outlook I saved the file in the folder where you wish:

Now the question is:
***How to read the second line of txt before saving?***

```
Public Sub SalvarAnexo(Item As MailItem)

    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String

    MsgBox "Mensagem Recebida de " & Item.Sender & "!"

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "txt" Then
            FileName = "C:\temp\" & Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        End If
    Next Atmt

End Sub
```

Comment: As far your code does not read any txt file. It saves attachment to temp folder. What's the question?

Comment: I need to read the text file before to use the code above, because on the second line of text file in attachment have the date that I need to create the folder where I go save the file.

Comment: What's the structure of txt file? Does entire second line is a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FileScriptingObject` to grab the second line of the text file like so.

```
Public Sub SalvarAnexo(Item)

    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strTest As String

    MsgBox "Mensagem Recebida de " & Item.Sender & "!"

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right$(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "txt" Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            FileName = "C:\temp\" & Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
             strTest = objFile.ReadLine
            strTest = objFile.ReadLine
            objFile.Close
            MsgBox "Your date is " & strTest
        End If
    Next Atmt

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for reading attached files on the fly. You need to save the attachment on the disk as a file and then open it for reading the second line. Also you may consider using the low-level code (or any third-party wrapper) - Extended MAPI. It allows to open an attachment as a stream of bytes.

Comment: Do you have a exemple using the low-level code (or any third-party wrapper) - Extended MAPI

Comment: Try using Redemption.